# how to upload a multiple images in gmail from web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to uploading a multiple images from a folder in Gmail,does it possible in web driver by using robot class.

```
  driver.findElement(By.className("aoT")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.className("aoT")).sendKeys("hi");
  WebElement frame1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='Am Al editable LW-avf']"));
  frame1.click();
  frame1.sendKeys("mailBody");
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='a1 aaA aMZ']")).click();
    //click on attachment icon
        StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("E:\\cv\\");
       //upload your file using RobotClass
       //attach your path where file is located.
       Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
       Robot robot = new Robot();
       Thread.sleep(5000);
       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
       robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
       robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
       Thread.sleep(6000);
       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
       robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
       Thread.sleep(10000);
```

E:/cv---- contains number of file so need to know to select all files from particular folder. Thanks!

Comment: Please try to improve this question by showing us your best good faith attempt and by asking a much more specific question over just what confuses you. So please, give it a try.

Comment: Yes, we can upload multiple file at a time. But Is that Robot class Key working??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

1. You can accumulate all the File paths of the images you want to upload in an array like this:

   ```
   String arr[] = {"\"D:\\Images\\default.jpg\"", "\"E:\\Images\\plant4.jpg\"", "\"F:\\Jpeg-image.jpeg\""};
   ```

   **NOTE: The image needn't be from the same location**
2. Concatenate all the contents of the array of file paths(above) in a single string like this:

   `String Arr_Final = arr[0];`

   ```
   for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
       Arr_Final+=arr[i]; 
   }
   ```
3. Put the Final String as a parameter while creating object of **StringSelection** class like this:

   `StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(Arr_Final);`

Now, when this string gets pasted in the "File Name" field of the dialog box, it will be represented like this:
**`"D:\Images\default.jpg""E:\Images\plant4.jpg""F:\Jpeg-image.jpeg"`**

Then, when the **Open button** gets clicked, all the concerned images starts getting uploaded.
Hope this helps..